# texture a line in openGL

Tags: c, opengl

I would like to draw a line that is many colors in OpenGL. I've generated a `GL_TEXTURE_1D` object, and used `glTexCoord1i` to assign coordinates to different vertices in my line (drawn using `GL_LINE_STRIP`) but my line comes out white. Is this the wrong approach? Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: my question was not "What am i doing wrong" or "How do i do this", it was "Is this a reasonable thing to do, or should i try to accomplish this using some other mechanism?"

Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Did you enable texturing (via `glEnable`)? Also, why was this downvoted?

Comment: I did enable texturing. Not sure why it's downvoted.

Comment: Perhaps provide some code?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: I'm guessing it was downvoted because it's completely unanswerable due to lack of critical information, thus showing a lack of effort on the part of the person asking the question.

Comment: That being said, this question seems entirely salvageable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted any code or elaborated on what you want to do, so telling you how to "accomplish this" is, as Nicol Bolas has pointed out, nearly impossible. However, I would check that your texture coordinates match the type you specified with `glTexCoord1i`. Are you perhaps using floats instead?

If you can't end up texturing a line (the Internets say this isn't possible but there's nothing official I can find), you can draw a very thin rectangle instead. This you *can* texture.

Comment: This is what i ended up doing, drawing a thin rectangle. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 9):

Line texturing works on at least one system:

[image: textured line]

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

GLuint tex = 0;
void init()
{
    glGenTextures( 1, &tex );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_1D, tex );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    unsigned char buf[ 32 * 4 ];
    for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( buf ); i += 4 )
    {
        buf[ i+0 ] = rand() % 255;
        buf[ i+1 ] = rand() % 255;
        buf[ i+2 ] = rand() % 255;
        buf[ i+3 ] = 255;
    }
    glTexImage1D( GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, 4, sizeof( buf ) / 4, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf );
}

void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( -2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_1D );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_1D, tex );
    glColor3ub( 255, 255, 255 );

    glLineWidth( 10 );
    glBegin( GL_LINES );
    glTexCoord1i( 0 );
    glVertex2i( -1, -1 );
    glTexCoord1i( 1 );
    glVertex2i(  1,  1 );
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 640, 480 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```